# Can I exclude country specific users without breaking Google anayltics tracking?

Tags: php, geolocation, ip

I really need to stop USA based visitors proceeding to buy products on our UK only website. We are getting a lot of fraud from USA based IP's. I have this nice solution ready to go live, but will it stop Google Analytics and any other USA based tracking scripts working on my website? Does anyone have a better solution?

```
    // Cut non UK countries out of going any further:
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$country = getCountryFromIP($ip, " NamE ");

if (strtolower($country) == "united states") {
    $pageOutput =  file_get_contents("country.exclusion.html");
    $pageOutput = str_replace("<quote:site-wide-footer-tracking.html>", file_get_contents("../static-includes/site-wide-footer-tracking.php"), $pageOutput );
```

Comment: You could also add a check for the UserAgent, and explicitly pass Googlebot.

Comment: IP address is not intended for user identification. You really should not block IPs, as one might use proxies, so you would bust legitimate users while this same technology allows any hacker to bypass your 'security'. User-Agent is even easier to forge. You have to accept that there will be requests the server must answer, and guard those operations that modify data, place orders, etc. with proper authentication schemes. To guard against overload, e.g. by a DoS attack, use a firewall. Otherwise you'll end up raking with your fork and eating with your rake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better way of doing this would be to prevent US based users from completing certain actions:

- Stop them adding a product to basket
- On the product page hide any 'Add to Cart' button and replace it with some simple 'This product is not available in your country' text.

This will prevent them from ever purchasing a product but still make sure Google and other US based entities can browse your site without restriction.

Comment: Good idea! I've removed my form from my results page but all tracking scripts remain!